# Avoid Cookieless 302 redirects for certain paths

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webforms

given an existing webforms app with a web.config that has...

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" ...
```

I've added a webapi to the project but it means any request coming in gets a 302 response and given a "cookie" in the url.

How can I make the sessionstate cookieless ignore a certain path ( like /api )

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question since this was super painful to find the right information and work out what's going on.

I wanted to use WebApi v2 and to be able to use from an existing webforms session based application, and also use it using any other more standard authentication strategy.

The code below is a mostly complete example of how to embed WebApi into WebForms and support both Session based and Basic Authentication.

So in Global.asax, I just call `MyWebApi.Global.Start();`

The key thing of why I was getting redirects was due to the code to recover session state for the webapi.   If you return a **`SessionControllerHandler`** and there is no session, then it will do a redirect to get a cookie, and in cookieless mode it adds it to the URL.   This was a disaster for a proxy I'm using.  However, by checking to see if it's trying to use a standard Authorization mechanisim and returning  a normal WebApi route handler it doesn't go through a 302 redirect.   It then filters through to Authroization function that determines if it's using standard Authorization or Session based and then validates  ( this part would need customizing depending on how you do that in your application )

```
public static class Global
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Register);
    }

    private static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var httpControllerRouteHandler = typeof(HttpControllerRouteHandler).GetField("_instance",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        if (httpControllerRouteHandler != null)
        {
            httpControllerRouteHandler.SetValue(null,
                new Lazy<HttpControllerRouteHandler>(() => new SessionHttpControllerRouteHandler(), true));
        }
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthenticationFilter());
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
    }
}

public class SessionControllerHandler : HttpControllerHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public SessionControllerHandler(RouteData routeData)
        : base(routeData)
    {
    }
}

public class SessionHttpControllerRouteHandler : HttpControllerRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Get("Authorization") != null)
        {
            return new HttpControllerHandler(requestContext.RouteData);
        }
        return new SessionControllerHandler(requestContext.RouteData);
    }
}

public class AuthenticationFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!Authorize(actionContext))
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            return;
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }

    private static bool Authorize(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = actionContext.Request;
            var authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;
            var roles = new string[0]; 
            if (authorization != null)
            {
                if (authorization.Scheme == "Basic")
                {
                    var decodedToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authorization.Parameter));
                    var username = decodedToken.Substring(0, decodedToken.IndexOf(":", StringComparison.Ordinal));
                    var password = decodedToken.Substring(decodedToken.IndexOf(":", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);

                    if(ValidUser(username, password))
                    {
                        Thread.CurrentPrincipal =
                            new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username, "Basic"), roles);
                        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                        {
                            HttpContext.Current.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
                        }
                        return true;
                   } 
                }
            }
            var context = request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper;
            // Use your session...which is up to your implementation
            var user = context?.Session["User"]?.ToString(); 
            if (user != null)
            {
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(user, "Session"), roles);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```